# Is it possible to add new user Roles?

Tags: user-roles

I wonder if it is possible to create a new user role and give him special limited abilities?

I'd like to have some users who can only add events onto the calendar. They should only be able to work within events calendar taxonomy and edit add their posts but not publish them something like contributor but more limited!

Comment: Without programming knowledge you can add user roles and capabilities in WordPress by different free plugins, here is one of them [User Roles and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. WordPress has robust built-in [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) system desgined to do exactly what you are looking for.

To add a new role, use the [`add_role()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) function in your theme's `functions.php` or a plug-in like so:

```
$role = add_role( 'event_manager', 'Event Manager', array(
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability
) );

if ( null !== $role ) {
    echo 'Yay!  New role created!';
} else {
    echo 'Oh... the event_manager role already exists.';

}
```

To add a new capability, use the [`add_cap()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) function like this:

```
$role = get_role( 'event_manager' );
$role->add_cap( 'manage_events' );
```

Comment: It should be noted that you only need to add (and remove) a role once.  They get stored in the database, no need to do it on every page load. Also, roles are better suited to plugins, in my opinion.

Comment: Just wondering, shouldn't we create a function and use a hook add_action('huh-which-one'

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely possible with a plugin like [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/). You can create new roles and capabilities, but remember - you'll actually need inject these custom capabilities into your plugin. What you may want to do is just install the plugin and then modify the existing contributor role to suite your needs.

For really granular control, you could bundle that with the [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in functions.php file

```
add_role(
    'custom_editor',
    __( 'Custom Editor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
    )
);
```

Replace Custom Editor with your role name

Answer (score 0):

Besides pure code solutions, I would also suggest this free plugin I used   since several years ago, and still. It's really stable and reliable, and actively updated.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/